# Android - Multiple LinearLayouts positioning?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-linearlayout, margin

I am trying to create multiple linear layouts inside main LinearLayout. But i am having some trouble with margin. Here is my code and output: -

```
public class CustomActivity extends Activity {

private LinearLayout mainLayout; 
Float value;
int dpi;
private String[] data = new String[] {"Hello World", "Hello World", "Hello World", "Hello World", ""};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom);
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    value = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    dpi = Math.round(value);
    addLayouts();
}

private void addLayouts() {
    int marginBottom = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        OutLinedLL linearLayout = new OutLinedLL(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dpi*22,dpi*35);
        if(i==0)
        {   
            linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            params.setMargins(dpi*7, dpi, dpi*4, marginBottom);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
            mainLayout.addView(linearLayout);
        }
        else 
        {
            count += dpi*2;
            Log.e("Count", count+"");
            marginBottom -= (dpi*28)+count;
            Log.e("Margin Bottom", marginBottom+"");
            linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            params.setMargins(dpi*7, dpi, dpi*4, marginBottom);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
            mainLayout.addView(linearLayout);
        }
        marginBottom = 0;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_custom, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Stack Trace: -

```
09-29 11:49:23.844: E/Count(16149): 40
09-29 11:49:23.844: E/Margin Bottom(16149): -600
09-29 11:49:23.852: E/Count(16149): 80
09-29 11:49:23.852: E/Margin Bottom(16149): -640
09-29 11:49:23.852: E/Count(16149): 120
09-29 11:49:23.852: E/Margin Bottom(16149): -680
09-29 11:49:23.852: E/Count(16149): 160
09-29 11:49:23.852: E/Margin Bottom(16149): -720
```

Output :- [image]

As you can see margin bottom isn't same for all the layouts. I am unable to find out why its happening. I am trying to learn custom views at the moment so any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what should the final layout look like?

Comment: exactly what i am trying to make it look but with equal margins. I want first layout(red) to be static and rest of the layouts hanging at the bottom of parent. I am having trouble with setting equal margins between all layouts. :(

Comment: Give weights.. double weight to first one and rest equal weights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this bit is your problem:

```
marginBottom -= (dpi*28)+count;
```

You are changing the amount of margin on each loop through.  Just set it to a static value and all your views should have the same margin.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I understand what you want you final layout to look like.

However, it sounds like a relative layout with the linear layouts would achieve the desired look and function for your purpose while being "lighter".

If I misunderstood you goal, I am sorry, but in that case it might help it you could be clearer in the question.